# How can i extract the links from the site that contains pagination?(using selenium)

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I want to extract the links from the following site but it does include pagination:
[I want to extract link under the **MoreInfo Button:**](https://www.usta.com/en/home/play/facility-listing.html?searchTerm=&distance=5000000000&address=Palo%20Alto,%20%20CA)

**I'm using the following snippet:**

```
import time
import requests
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import re


browser = webdriver.Chrome()
time.sleep(5)
browser.get('https://www.usta.com/en/home/play/facility-listing.html?searchTerm=&distance=5000000000&address=Palo%20Alto,%20%20CA')
wait = WebDriverWait(browser,15)

def extract_data(browser):
    links = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='seeMoreBtn']/a")
    return [link.get_attribute('href') for link in links]


element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right']")))
max_pages = int(re.search(r'\d+ de (\d+)', element.text).group(1), re.UNICODE)
# extract from the current (1) page
print("Page 1")
print(extract_data(browser))

for page in range(2, max_pages + 1):
    print("Page %d" % page)
    next_page = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right']").click()
    print(extract_data(browser))
    print("-----")
```

when i run the above script i got this error**(I'm not too much familiar with regex as well just exploring the concept)**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Python/CSV/testingtesting.py", line 29, in <module>
    max_pages = int(re.search(r'\d+ de (\d+)', element.text).group(1), re.UNICODE)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

**Please suggest me the solution if possible. Somehow i manage to extract the link using wait and clicking on pagination link. But its time taking as have added almost 13seconds of wait in it and that working code is as follows:**

```
import time
import requests
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import re



# ----------------------------------------------HANDLING-SELENIUM-STUFF-------------------------------------------------
linkList = []
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
time.sleep(5)
driver.get('https://www.usta.com/en/home/play/facility-listing.html?searchTerm=&distance=5000000000&address=Palo%20Alto,%20%20CA')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,8)
time.sleep(7)

for i in range(1,2925):
    time.sleep(3)
    # wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "//div[@class='seeMoreBtn']/a")))
    links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='seeMoreBtn']/a")
    # print(links.text)
    time.sleep(3)

    #appending extracted links to the list
    for link in links:
        value=link.get_attribute("href")
        # linkList.append(value)
        with open('test.csv','a',encoding='utf-8',newline='') as fp:
            writer = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
            writer.writerow([value])
    # print(i,"  ",)
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right']").click()
    time.sleep(6)
```

Comment: What are the *links* that you want to extract? Do you need the values of `@href` from each "MORE INFO"?

Comment: yeah i want the value of @href from the MORE INFO button. Somehow i managed to extract those values using the 2nd code that i have pasted above. But its time taking. Is there any alternative way so that i can reduce the time by 5-7 seconds as there're 2925 pages in the pagination section?

Comment: because after loading pages it takes 2-3 seconds to update the new values with previous one. and in that period of time if i write the file then the old values will be written

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code to get required data without extra "sleeps":

```
import requests
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException



# ----------------------------------------------HANDLING-SELENIUM-STUFF-------------------------------------------------
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.usta.com/en/home/play/facility-listing.html?searchTerm=&distance=5000000000&address=Palo%20Alto,%20%20CA')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 8)

links = []

while True:
    new_links = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "MORE INFO")))
    links.extend([link.get_attribute("href") for link in new_links])

    try:
        next_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li[title='Next page']>a")))
        next_button.click()
    except TimeoutException:
        break
    wait.until(EC.staleness_of(new_links[-1]))

#  Do whatever you need with links
```

Comment: again getting duplicate values but its really fast. where should i add almost 3 seconds of wait until next page will be loaded fully? will it work for after "EC.staleness" statement?

Comment: or after click function?

Comment: sir, thanks thanks and thanks a ton for all your help.

Comment: Hmm... Actually I didn't check the uniqueness of results. `wait.until(EC.staleness_of(new_links[-1]))` is wait for the last link to be refreshed, so I thought that whole list of links will be updated... Do you still need the fix for the same?

Comment: yeah if you could then it will be great... but you've cope it tremendously without any wait. 3 second of wait won't be an issue as i was using 12 seconds within loop which means that complexity rose to hell. but you saved my day almost